# Is work logging supported by Phabricator or Can we bring in a work logging feature?

Tags: phabricator, agile-project-management, task-management

We were checking the feasibility of using Phabricator in our software development activities.

We are currently using JIRA and is looking for a lighter replacement. We feel JIRA as a generic tool that doesn't only focus on software development and Phabricator for us looks lighter and well integrated.

One feature we couldn't find is Work logging. Currently we are using jira work logging feature for extracting data for project management reporting.

So basically my query is

1. Is work logging feature available in Phabricator ?
2. Would it be possible to extend the Phabricator for this purpose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, yes, there is a work logging feature called Phrequent. It is one of the prototype applications in Phabricator (prototypes must be turned on from Config).

However, it has a lot of missing features. While individuals can start and stop work time on tasks, they cannot edit or delete time entries, and the reporting features are less than ideal (you can only view by person, not by time range or task). More features are planned, though they appear to be low priority right now for the core development team.

Comment: Thank you @jasonmc92 for the details.